# document.onkeypress is not working, how to fix?

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason the following code should not return anything in my console log?!

```
document.onkeypress =  zx();

function zx(){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
} // zx
```

`window.onkeypress` also doesn't work.

Other attempts has been made, like these:

```
document.onkeypress =  zx(event);

function zx(event){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
} // zx
```

-

```
document.onkeypress =  zx;

function zx(){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
} // zx
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your third attempt is missing the definition of event in the function definition.

Also keyCode doesn't do what you think it does: [event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/event.keyCode)

read the notes section.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Omit the parenthesis on the call, you do not need to specify them.

Solution:

```
document.onkeypress =  zx;
function zx(e){
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode
    console.log(charCode);
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RXXYj/125/)

Comment: done already but it still doesn't work. I just get '0' on my console when I press the mouse but nothing when I press the keys.

Comment: @Saturnix, I am made a demo. Check them out

Answer (score 2):

When attaching a `function` to `event` you don't need the `()`

Just do:

```
document.onkeypress =  zx; //note! don't use the ()

function zx(){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
} // zx
```

if you are using chrome try to catch the right value by

```
function zx(e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    console.log(key);
} // zx
```

Comment: if you see my third attempt, you'll see that I've already tried it but it still doesn't work :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.onkeypress = displayunicode;
function displayunicode(event){
    var charCode = (typeof event.which == "number") ? event.which : event.keyCode
    console.log(charCode )
}
```

This will work.

Answer (score -1):

Your function needs to define 'event'.

```
// assign a reference to zx; but don't call zx
document.onkeypress =  zx;

// event needs to be defined
function zx(event){
    console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

keyCode will sometimes be 0

See this page: [event.keyCode on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/event.keyCode)

You probably want to use event.which

```
    document.onkeypress = zx;
    function zx(event) {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    }
```

Comment: `console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));` doesn't really give the right results.  When you do this when `event.which === 40`, then you get "(". But 40 is the Down arrow.